# Filtering an OptionSet based on another field selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have one optionSet named STATES.  Another named RESTAURANTS.

My goal is to filter the Restaurants optionSet according to what State is selected.

My current method is to design the values of the options where:

```
States[0] = 1000
States[1] = 2000
States[2] = 3000
```

Then, Restaurants:

```
Restaurants[3] = 1003
Restaurants[30] = 2004
```

I then iterate through the Restaurants when the States field is changed.  If the restaurant value is not in the range of the selected State, I call removeOption(Restaurant.value).

My problem is that if the State is changed more than once, every value will have been removed, because I don't "refresh" the optionset or "replaceOption".

Is there any way to display all optionSet values after they have been removed via removeOption, via javascript?

Comment: post your html and code you are using

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is create a dependant picklist. There is a sample for this in the SDK, it is explained in [this blog post for Crm 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/06/08/new-dependent-picklist-sample.aspx) and [this MSDN article for 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594433.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

A far better design would be to have two custom entities: one for states, one for restaurants.
The restaurants entity would have a required (mandatory) lookup field (for a N:1 relationship) to States.
Add lookups to both State and Restaurant where you would have had the picklists.
You can then use built-in feature to filter one lookup based on the value of another. No code, no stress, almost zero maintenance.

Don't forget that you need to make sure users have "append to" privileges on

You can set up records for all the states easily enough by importing, and don't let users amend these. Import restaurants including the State information. You can use security roles to determine which users are allowed to create new restaurant records in future to make this really easy to keep up to date without it being an admin job.

I know this does not answer the question you asked about filtering picklists, but I am certain it answers your implied business requirement behind that.

Comment: Watch out for the filtering not being enforced in reverse. E.g. A filters B, so you select an option from A, then selected a filtered option from B, then you can change A to be something totally unrelated to B. You would need JavaScript to clear B when A changes.

Comment: True, and this is the same no matter what approach is taken (picklists or lookups).
You could make field A read-only when B is filled in, or as you suggest clear B if A is changed. I also like to filter A based on B and vice versa, or even to change A to the correct parent of B if B changes (if you allow users to trn B's filter off, which you may not want to do). It all depends on the exact usage. If users may know B without being sure of A then let them choose B first and fill in A for them as an alternative path.